# Ag grid sorting not happening when there is a empty field

Tags: angular, ag-grid, columnsorting

i have a ag grid table with 10 columns, And for all the columns globally i am enabling the sorting as below,

`enableSorting= "true"`
inside the `<ag-grid-angular`.

One of our column has date attribute and it contains few empty value as well. For normal list it's sorting as expected but when it comes to a list with empty value its not sorting properly.

Is there any way i can restrict empty value to the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could find a way for above. By using a custom comparator, here are the snippets.

```
dateComparator(date1, date2) {
  if(!date1){
    date1 = '04/23/2300';
  } else if(!date2){
    date2 = '05/23/2300';
  }
  if (date1 === undefined || date1 === null || date1.length !== 10) {
    return null;
  }
  else{
    var yearNumber = date1.substring(6, 10);
    var dayNumber  = date1.substring(3, 5);
    var  monthNumber = date1.substring(0, 2);
    var result = yearNumber * 10000 + monthNumber * 100 + dayNumber;
    var date1Number = result;
  }
  if (date2 === undefined || date2 === null || date2.length !== 10) {
    return null;
  }
  else{
    var yearNumber2 = date2.substring(6, 10);
    var dayNumber2  = date2.substring(3, 5);
    var  monthNumber2 = date2.substring(0, 2);
    var result2 = yearNumber2 * 10000 + monthNumber2 * 100 + dayNumber2;
    var date2Number = result2;
  }
  // var date1Number = this.monthToComparable(date1);
  // var date2Number = this.monthToComparable(date2);
  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }
  return Number(date1Number)- Number(date2Number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom comparator to your date column like this-

```
  {
    field: 'date',
    comparator: dateComparator,
  },
```

And define a custom comparator to keep nulls at the last

```
function dateComparator(date1, date2, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {
  if (date1 === null && date2 === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1 === null) {
    return isInverted ? 1 : -1;
  }
  if (date2 === null) {
    return isInverted ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return date1 - date2;
}
```

This should work if your dates are passed as dates to ag-grid. You can follow this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#example-custom-sorting) if dates are passed as strings.

Comment: Yes you are right, i have re posted along with the ans. Here i am just setting empty dates to a random big dates.

Thank you :-)